# How to Stop Frame Clipping

Tags: wpf, frame

I have a Page built in xBap with a frame, and another page in the frame
How can I take out a control from the inner page outside of a frame in visual,

in other words, I want to stop clipping for the frame.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML_Browser_Applications#XBAP_Limitations).

Comment: for Info, the frame is WPF frame, and the application is FullTrust

Comment: still, not possible, you could write a normal wpf app and deploy them with ClickOnce: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx